# SQL Query returning duplicate values

Tags: mysql, web, ranking

I am developing a ranking system for an online game webite and am having trouble with the query that returns duplicate values.

**The query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `personajes`,`ranking_pvp` ORDER BY `victorias` DESC LIMIT 30
```

**The result:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A3wJ.jpg

**The duplicated values​:**

```
`nombre` , `victorias` , `derrotas`
```

**The 'personajes' table:**

- **`id`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`nombre`** VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
- **`sexo`** TINYINT(2) NOT NULL
- **`clase`** SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL
- **`color1`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`color2`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`color3`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`kamas`** BIGINT(32) NOT NULL
- **`puntosHechizo`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`capital`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`energia`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000'
- **`nivel`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`xp`** BIGINT(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
- **`talla`** INT(11) NOT NULL
- **`gfx`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`alineacion`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`honor`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`deshonor`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`nivelAlin`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nivel alineamiento',
- **`cuenta`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`vitalidad`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`fuerza`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sabiduria`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`inteligencia`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`suerte`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`agilidad`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`mostrarAmigos`** TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
- **`mostrarAlineacion`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`canal`** VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '*#%!pi$:?',
- **`mapa`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '8479',
- **`celda`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`porcVida`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
- **`hechizos`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`objetos`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`posSalvada`** VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '8570,314',
- **`zaaps`** VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
- **`oficios`** VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
- **`xpMontura`** TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`montura`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
- **`titulo`** VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`esposo`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`tienda`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`mercante`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sFuerza`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sInteligencia`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sAgilidad`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sSuerte`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sVitalidad`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`sSabiduria`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`restriccionesA`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '8192',
- **`restriccionesB`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`encarnacion`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
- **`emotes`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`ornamento`** TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`ornamentos`** VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
- **`misiones`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`coleccion`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`resets`** SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`almanax`** TEXT NOT NULL,
- **`ultimoNivel`** INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- **`setsRapidos`** TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_spanish_ci'
- PRIMARY KEY (**`id`**)

**The 'ranking_pvp' table:**

- **`id`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`nombre`** VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
- **`victorias`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`derrotas`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- **`nivelAlineacion`** INT(11) NOT NULL,
- PRIMARY KEY (**`id`**)

Someone could increase my query to remove the duplicate values?

Waiting and Thx ;)

Comment: you're selecting from two different tables with NO `join` conditions at all, which means you're going to get a cartesian join, `table1 x table2`. e.g. 100 records in table 1, 50 records in table2, you're going to get 100x50 = 5000 result rows.

Comment: How would my query with `JOIN`?

Comment: no idea. you need for the two tables to share at least one common field to join on, but since you've provided no details about the structure, we can't help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Updated.
Equal column: **`personajes.nombre`** and **`ranking_pvp.nombre`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the info you just added as a comment:

```
SELECT *
FROM personajes p
JOIN ranking_pvp rp ON rp.nombre = p.nombre
ORDER BY `victorias` DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: I solve my problem using the query:
`SELECT * FROM personajes JOIN ranking_pvp ON personajes.nombre = ranking_pvp.nombre ORDER BY victorias DESC LIMIT 30`.

Basically the same query yours. Only you "renamed" the tables. Anyway , thank you!